# Use of var secret in npm mongoose-encryption module

Tags: node.js, database, encryption, backend, password-encryption

```
var secret = process.env.SOME_LONG_UNGUESSABLE_STRING;
userSchema.plugin(encrypt, { secret: secret });
```

Was using npm `mongoose-encryption` module for password `encryption`, but I couldn't understand why that variable `secret` is used. What's the role of that variable?

Comment: `process.env.SOME_LONG_UNGUESSABLE_STRING` is a secret key that is stored in `.env` file and later stored in secret `variable`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As kedar sedai said in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62755705/use-of-var-secret-in-npm-mongoose-encryption-module#comment110976763_62755705), `process.env.SOME_LONG_UNGUESSABLE_STRING` is a secret key stored in a `.env` file **or** in your OS' environment variables.

This secret is going to be used as specified by AES-256-CBC (the encryption method `mongoose-encryption` [implements](https://github.com/joegoldbeck/mongoose-encryption#how-it-works)); that means your `SOME_LONG_UNGUESSABLE_STRING` is going to be used as part of the cipher method, applying your string as both encryption key and decryption key (because of this you can call AES a **symmetric algorithm**).

Consequently, if you change this string nothing that was encrypted before will be decryptable anymore unless you use the same exactly secret.

Simply put, the "secret" variable is pretty much what makes your encryption safe, and that's also why it should be unguessable. You can read more about this method [here.](https://searchsecurity.techtarget.com/definition/Advanced-Encryption-Standard)